# Map chart: How to summarize multiple counties?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with a map chart I want to create in Excel.

| County | Area |
| --- | --- |
| Emsland | 1 |
| Essen | 2 |
| Gelsenkirchen | 2 |
| Grafschaft Bentheim | 1 |
| Recklinghausen | 2 |
| Unna | 2 |

I am pretty sure this is not to be solved with the Interface in Excel, but this question has been flagged off-topic before. I think this can or could be solved with VBA, since Excel does not automatically allow users to select multiple rows in a map chart and them create a frame only around the outer parts.

I need to have a frame around all counties that connect to a specific area. In the end I want not to differentiate the areas by colour (which is standardized resolution in excel), but by just having a frame around them.

Regards and thanks